# How to debug a custom activity designer?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I have a custom workflow activity for which I've written a designer. Unfortunately, when I drag my activity from the toolbox onto the workflow designer surface, I get an error ("Could not generate view for ..."). I suspect that some code in my designer (which is running inside of Visual Studio) is at fault.

How can I debug the code in the designer? Since it normally runs inside of VS, I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start a second copy of VS2010 and attach the debugger to that instance to debug your designer.